# how to handle read time out selenium errors

Tags: java, selenium

When running selenium tests, I get the following error:

running selenium on ubuntu14. chrome driver. Selenium version 2.53.0

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

```
tests/share_page {
    sessionId: null,
    status: 13,
    state: 'unhandled error',
    value: {
        message: 'Read timed out',
        suppressed: [],
        localizedMessage: 'Read timed out',
        cause: null,
        class: 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException',
        hCode: 1836076435,
        screen: null
    },
    class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
    hCode: 261327164
}
```

It runs the other tests but gets stuck on one test and I get the error above. Is there a setting I should set to help against this error?maybe it's a memory problem? If so how do I determine how much memory to give selenium

Comment: Can you specify browser please?

Comment: Do you specify path to chromedriver?

Comment: Yes the other tests run, but it fails when running the last test